# Insert array structure

Tags: sql, postgresql

Синтаксис вставки конкретных столбцов для массива структур, при этом нужно вставить массив из неполных структур.

Пример Таблица (column_name1, ..., column_namei) column_namei = array [структура] структура = [текст field1_name, текст field2_id, текст field3_phone, текст field4_address] Хочу вставить [{'name1', '+7 (495) 383 88, 22 '}, {' name2 ',' +5 (555) 838 44 44 '}, {' name3 ',' +3 (333) 333 33 33 '}]

Comment: Укажите СУБД!  Ну и да, по-хорошему эти структуры должны быть в отдельной таблице, ибо нормализация.

Comment: Posql. К сожалению нет возможности использовать вспомогательные таблицы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Из вашего вопроса не ясны многие детали.  Вот простой пример таблицы
с массивом композитных типов:

```sql
CREATE TYPE typ_1 AS (
  name  TEXT
, phone TEXT
)
;

CREATE TABLE t_1 (
  id    BIGINT  PRIMARY KEY GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY
, field typ_1[]
)
;

INSERT INTO t_1
  (                                                      field)
VALUES
  (CAST(ARRAY[('main', '1234'), ('other', '5678')] AS typ_1[]))
;

SELECT id
     , field[1].name
     , field[1].phone
     , field[2].name
     , field[2].phone
  FROM t_1
;
```

Comment: Спасибо, это похоже на то, что мне необходимо, но всё же: 1) Невозможно вставить исключительно поле name в вашем примере? Массив из значений для этого поля? 2) Вы правы, что использование структур и массивов не соответствуют постулатам взаимодействия с СУБД. Но в случае если у меня больше количество столбцов (120+, при этом из них 30 представлены структурами, и 10 столбцов имеют массивы значений) каким образом было бы целесообразнее хранить данные, как лучше организовать это, может быть вы посоветуете книжки для лучшего осознания?

Comment: @Петр  Первое не до конца понял.  Поставьте `NULL` или `''` на место телефона, если его нет.

Второе — вопрос слишком обширный, но 120 столбцов со структурами — это ужас.  Проведите [нормализацию](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0), иначе проблемы у вас будут хоть со структурами, хоть без них, хоть в *PostgreSQL,* хоть где.

Книг посоветовать не могу, так как в работе руководствуюсь правилами нормализации, личным опытом, документацией, бенчмарками, и статьями об особенностях конкретных СУБД.

Comment: Я знаком с нормальными формами, но получается будет огромное количество таблиц, работа с которыми будет весьма затруднена. Не существует ли альтернативного пути организации данных?

Comment: Без конкретики ответить сложно.  Да и «весьма затруднена» у всех своё, ибо некоторым элементарные `JOIN` не под силу.  Можете глянуть в сторону [документоориентированных СУБД](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%A1%D0%A3%D0%91%D0%94), но тут я вам уже не помощник.